# Windows 10 folder in This PC not being recognized as special

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

My `This PC` folder has the six standard folders - `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Music`, `Pictures`, and `Videos`.

When I open the properties window for any of these folders besides `Downloads`, I get something resembling the following:

[image: properties window for documents]

Whereas if I open the properties window for `Downloads`, I get this:

[image]

Note that the window does not have a Location tab. Also note that the actual location has been set to the non-standard location `C:\Users` instead of `C:\Users\jeff`. I believe I changed this a long time ago but have since forgotten about it.

The `Downloads` folder located in `C:\Users` has essentially replaced my home directory. The directory `jeff` does not even exist in the `C:\Users` folder. However, when I type in `C:\Users\jeff` into the File Explorer, it takes me to `C:\Users\Downloads`.

I've sort of passively accepted all this wonkiness for a while, but I'd like to actually return my PC to normal. As in, make the `Downloads` folder located in `This PC` to map to `C:\Users\jeff\Downloads`, where `C:\Users\jeff` actually exists as a distinct directory.

Comment: To answer this, I would either need to see your PC (to diagnose the problem, which isn't going to happen here on SU), or you need to tell me exactly what you did to change the users folder.

Comment: The only way to resolve this problem is by fixing the shell folder values for Downloads, in the registry. See [Windows 10 User Shell Folders Restore Default Paths](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/) and [Fix Shell Folders Like Music and Videos Merged and Pointing to Same Folder](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-folders-merged-music-videos-same-folder/)

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you.  Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to return to a standard folder hierarchy, unless you can remember how you originally implemented the change (or can effectively reverse-engineer it), the most reliable method would be to backup all of the pertinent data within your profile, delete it, and then recreate it.  The entire process would be rather time consuming, but it would achieve your goal.

1. Open a search box by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `netplwiz` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. If applicable, acknowledge the `UAC` prompt by selecting `Yes`
4. If is isn't already selected, check the box to ensure that `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`
   [image: Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer]
5. Select the user you want to delete (a.k.a. Jeff) and click `Remove`
   [image: Select the user you want to delete]
6. Click on `Yes` to confirm
   [image: Click on Yes to confirm]

Once you are done, create your new "Jeff" user profile and restore your personal files accordingly.

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5464-user-account-delete-windows-10-a.html))